# How to make simple graph in objective c using UIBezierPath?

Tags: objective-c, graph, uiview, uibezierpath

Very simple a make graph and draw a line using UIBezierPath

At fist you create a subClass of UIView

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>  

@interface GraphView : UIView  

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *verticalPointsMarray;  
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *horizontalPointsMarray;  
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *graphValueMArray;  
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *graphPointsMArray;  


@property(nonatomic,assign)NSInteger       numberOfVerticlaLine;  
@property(nonatomic,assign)NSInteger       numberOfHorizontalLine;  

@end
```

Finally Draw a line See the this code

```
//  GraphView.m  
//  MapLocation  
//  
//  Created by Md. Khurshid on 22/07/16.  
//  Copyright © 2016 Md. Khurshid. All rights reserved.  
//  

#import "GraphView.h"  

#define LEFT_POINT   @"leftPoint"  
#define RIGHT_POINT  @"rightPoint"  
#define TOP_POINT    @"topPoint"  
#define BOTTOM_POINT @"bottomPoint"  
#define MIN_NUMBER_OF_HORIZONTALLINE 1  
#define GRAPHL_INE_COLOR  colorWithRed:68/255.0 green:127/255.0   blue:200/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor  

@implementation GraphView  
{
    UIBezierPath *_aPath;  
}  

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.  
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during   animation.  
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {  


    self.verticalPointsMarray   = [NSMutableArray new];  
    self.horizontalPointsMarray = [NSMutableArray new];  
    self.graphValueMArray       = [NSMutableArray new];  

    //Add the graph points array You change The graph point value and graph drawing line change  
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"0"];    
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"1"];    
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"0"];  
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"2"];    
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"0"];    
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"3"];    
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"1"];    

    //Make a vertical point  
    float width = (self.frame.size.width-40)/6;  
    for (NSInteger i=0; i < 7; i++) {  

        float x_witdh = width * i;  
        x_witdh = x_witdh +20;  
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];  
        [dictionary setObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:  
                               CGPointMake(x_witdh,   self.frame.size.height)]  
                       forKey:TOP_POINT];  
        [dictionary setObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:  
                               CGPointMake(x_witdh,0)]  
                       forKey:BOTTOM_POINT];  
        [self.verticalPointsMarray addObject:dictionary];  
    }  

    _numberOfHorizontalLine = [self maxValue:_graphValueMArray];  
    if (_numberOfHorizontalLine == 0) _numberOfHorizontalLine =   MIN_NUMBER_OF_HORIZONTALLINE;  
    float height = self.frame.size.height /_numberOfHorizontalLine;  

    //Make a horizontal point  
    for (NSInteger i=0; i <= _numberOfHorizontalLine; i++) {  

        float y_height = height * i;  
        if (i == 0) y_height =  y_height + 1;  
        if (i == _numberOfHorizontalLine && i != 0) y_height =  y_height - 1;  
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];  
        [dictionary setObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:  
                               CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width-  20,y_height)]  
                       forKey:LEFT_POINT];  
        [dictionary setObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:  
                               CGPointMake(20,y_height)]  
                       forKey:RIGHT_POINT];
        [self.horizontalPointsMarray addObject:dictionary];  
    }  
    [self drawVerticaLine];  
    [self drawHorizontalLine];  
    [self drawGraphLine];  
}  

- (void)drawVerticaLine {  

    _aPath  = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];  
    NSInteger dayArrayIndex = _verticalPointsMarray.count;  
    NSArray *dayArray = [self getShortedDay];  

    for (NSInteger i=0; i < self.verticalPointsMarray.count ; i++) {  

        NSDictionary *dictionary = [_verticalPointsMarray   objectAtIndex:i];  
        NSValue *value;  
        value = [dictionary objectForKey:TOP_POINT];  
        CGPoint leftPoint  =  [value CGPointValue];  
        value = [dictionary objectForKey:BOTTOM_POINT];  
        CGPoint rightPoint =  [value CGPointValue];  

        [_aPath moveToPoint:leftPoint];  

        if (!dayArrayIndex) {  
            [self addTitleLable:CGRectMake(leftPoint.x-10, leftPoint.y,   35,25) withTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dayArray   objectAtIndex:--dayArrayIndex]]];  
        } else {  

            [self addTitleLable:CGRectMake(leftPoint.x-26, leftPoint.y,   50,25) withTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dayArray   objectAtIndex:--dayArrayIndex]]];  
        }
        [_aPath addLineToPoint:rightPoint];  
    }  
    _aPath.lineWidth = 1.0;  
    [[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor] setStroke];  
    [_aPath stroke];  
}  

- (void)drawHorizontalLine {  

    _aPath    = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];  
    NSInteger title = _numberOfHorizontalLine;  
    for (NSInteger i=0; i <= _numberOfHorizontalLine; i++) {  

        NSDictionary *dictionary = [_horizontalPointsMarray   objectAtIndex:i];  
        NSValue *value;  
        value               = [dictionary objectForKey:LEFT_POINT];  
        CGPoint topPoint    = [value CGPointValue];  
        value               = [dictionary objectForKey:RIGHT_POINT];  
        CGPoint bottomPoint = [value CGPointValue];  

        [_aPath moveToPoint:topPoint];  
        [_aPath addLineToPoint:bottomPoint];  
        [self addTitleLable:CGRectMake(0, bottomPoint.y-15, 20, 30)  withTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",title--]];  
    }  
    _aPath.lineWidth = 1.0;  
    [[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor] setStroke];  
    [_aPath stroke];  
}  

- (void)drawGraphLine {  

    _aPath    = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];  
    NSDictionary *dictionary;  
    NSValue *value;  
    NSMutableArray *mArray = [NSMutableArray new];  
    self.graphPointsMArray = [NSMutableArray new];  
    NSValue *firstPointValue;  

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < _graphValueMArray.count; i++) {  

        NSInteger hIndex = _numberOfHorizontalLine;  
        for (NSInteger vIndex = 0; vIndex <= _numberOfHorizontalLine;   vIndex++) {  

            if (vIndex == [[_graphValueMArray objectAtIndex:i]intValue])   {  

                dictionary      = [_verticalPointsMarray   objectAtIndex:i];  
                value           = [dictionary objectForKey:BOTTOM_POINT];  
                CGPoint point  =  [value CGPointValue];  
                dictionary      = [_horizontalPointsMarray   objectAtIndex:hIndex];  
                value           = [dictionary objectForKey:LEFT_POINT];  
                CGPoint point1  =  [value CGPointValue];  
                [mArray addObject:[NSValue   valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(point.x,point1.y)]];  
                if (i== 0) firstPointValue = [NSValue   valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(point.x,point1.y)];  
                [_graphPointsMArray addObject:[NSValue   valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(point.x,point1.y)]];  
                break;  
            }  
            hIndex = hIndex - 1;  
        }

        if (mArray.count == 2) {  

            value = [mArray objectAtIndex:0];  
            CGPoint point1  = [value CGPointValue];  
            value = [mArray objectAtIndex:1];  
            CGPoint point2 = [value CGPointValue];  
            [_aPath moveToPoint:point2];  
            [_aPath addQuadCurveToPoint:point1 controlPoint:point2];  
            [mArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];  
            [self addPointViewWithFrame:CGRectMake(point1.x-4, point1.y-3, 8, 8)];  

        }  
    }  

    [_graphPointsMArray addObject:firstPointValue];  
    value = [mArray objectAtIndex:0];  
    CGPoint point  = [value CGPointValue];  
    [self addPointViewWithFrame:CGRectMake(point.x-5, point.y-4, 10,   10)];  
    _aPath.lineWidth = 2.0;  
    [[UIColor colorWithRed:68.0/255.0 green:127.0/255.0 blue:200.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] setStroke];  
    [_aPath stroke];  

    value = [_graphPointsMArray objectAtIndex:0];  
    point = [value CGPointValue];  
    [_aPath moveToPoint:point];      
    for (NSInteger index=0; index < _graphPointsMArray.count; index++) {  

        if (index == _graphPointsMArray.count-1) {  

            NSDictionary *dict =  [_horizontalPointsMarray lastObject];  
            value = [dict objectForKey:LEFT_POINT];  
            point = [value CGPointValue];  

        } else {  

            value = [_graphPointsMArray objectAtIndex:index];  
            point = [value CGPointValue];  

        }  
        [_aPath addLineToPoint:point];  
    }  

    [_aPath closePath];  
    CAShapeLayer *line = [CAShapeLayer layer];  
    line.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;  
    line.path = [_aPath CGPath];  
    line.lineWidth = 0.0;  
    line.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:68.0/255.0 green:127.0/255.0
                                      blue:200.0/255.0 alpha:0.2].CGColor;  
    [[self layer] addSublayer:line];  

}  
- (void)addTitleLable:(CGRect)frame withTitle:(NSString *)title {  

    UILabel *lable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];  
    lable.text  = title;  
    lable.font  = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];  
    lable.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;  
    [self addSubview:lable];  
}  

- (void)addPointViewWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {  

    UIView *view = [UIView new];  
    view.frame  = frame;  
    view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;  
    view.layer.cornerRadius  = frame.size.height/2;  
    view.backgroundColor     = [UIColor colorWithRed:68.0/255.0 green:127.0/255.0  
                                                blue:200.0/255.0   alpha:1.0];  
    [self addSubview:view];  
}  
- (NSArray *)getShortedDay {  

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter =[ [NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE"];  

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];  

    NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];  

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)  
    {
        NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-(i * (60 * 60 * 24)) sinceDate:now];  
        if ([[dateFormatter stringFromDate:now] isEqual:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]]) {  

            [results addObject:@"Today"];  
        } else {  

            [results addObject:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];  
        }   
    }  

    return results;
}

// get max value  
- (NSInteger )maxValue:(NSArray *)arrValue  
{
    float maxValue = 0.0;  
    for (NSInteger index=0 ;index <arrValue.count;index++) {  
        float compareValue = [[arrValue objectAtIndex:index] floatValue];  
        if (compareValue > maxValue) {  
            maxValue = compareValue;  
        }  
    }  
    return maxValue;  
}  
@end
```

Set the Graph value
 and build and run the project

```
self.graphValueMArray       = [NSMutableArray new];  
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"0"];  
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"1"];  
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"0"];  
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"2"];  
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"0"];  
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"3"];  
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"1"];
```

This graph is look like This:-

[Simple graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcxXQ.png)

And again change the value and run the project

```
self.graphValueMArray       = [NSMutableArray new];  
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"0"];  
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"10"];  
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"5"];  
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"7"];  
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"6"];  
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"9"];  
    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"2"];
```

[Simple Graph Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM0P3.png)

Comment: Is this a question or an answer? I am unable to understand what you are trying to ask. Do take a look at our [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: @dubes Question not clear but picture is clear to tell the the issue

Answer (score 0):

Hi Khurshid please follow the correction on your method,

**GraphView.h**

```
@interface GraphView : UIView


@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *verticalPointsMarray;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *horizontalPointsMarray;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *graphValueMArray;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *graphPointsMArray;

@property(nonatomic,assign)NSInteger       numberOfVerticlaLine;
@property(nonatomic,assign)NSInteger       numberOfHorizontalLine;

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect withPoint:(NSMutableArray *)pointsToDraw ;
```

**GraphView.m**

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect withPoint:(NSMutableArray *)pointsToDraw {


    self.verticalPointsMarray   = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.horizontalPointsMarray = [NSMutableArray new];
//    self.graphValueMArray       = [NSMutableArray new];
    self.graphValueMArray       = pointsToDraw;

    //Add the graph points array You change The graph point value and graph drawing line change

    //    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"0"];
    //    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"1"];
    //    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"0"];
    //    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"2"];
    //    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"0"];
    //    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"3"];
    //    [_graphValueMArray addObject:@"1"];
```

And method call will be,

```
self.graphView = [[GraphView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-60) ];
    [self.graphView drawRect:self.graphView.frame withPoint:_graphValueMArray];
    [self.graphView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]] ;
    [self.graphView setGraphPointsMArray:self.graphValueMArray];
    [self.view addSubview:self.graphView];
```

**All the best for any info feel free to contact**